# Write Internet Time to a file from windows command line

Tags: cmd.exe, ntp

I want to write the time of an internet time server to a text file from within windows server 2012 command line. Does someone knows how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess a Google search may help? You need to do your own research first, show what you've tried. We're not here to do your work. -1

Comment: Hi Dave, of course i did a google research. If you find the answer please, I'm all ears. My script for synch'en the domaincontrollers works fine but i cannot find a way to write the time of the internet time server (not the time on my own server of course) to a text file. I thought it would be very simple but can't find the ansewer on google.

Answer (score 0):

you can hit the NTP server using Telnet, and redirect the standard output to file, or parse it along the line in a script.

```
telnet <timeserver> <NTPport>
```

The server will respond by printing the current time in the response. from there you can grab the standard out, and parse it as you need to.

Note, some servers may use port 13 (daytime) instead of 123.